# NextJS + Storybook - Optional Chaining doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, next.js, storybook

[image: An underlying library uses optional chaining]

rehype-ignore - index.js has this code

```
import { visit } from 'unist-util-visit';
const rehypeIgnore = (options = {}) => {
    const { openDelimiter = 'rehype:ignore:start', closeDelimiter = 'rehype:ignore:end' } = options;
    return (tree) => {
        visit(tree, (node, index, parent) => {
            if (node.type === 'element' || node.type === 'root') {
                // const start = node.children.findIndex((item) => item.type === 'comment' && item.value === openDelimiter);
                // const end = node.children.findIndex((item) => item.type === 'comment' && item.value === closeDelimiter);
                // if (start > -1 && end > -1) {
                //   node.children = node.children.filter((_, idx) => idx < start || idx > end);
                // }
                let start = false;
                node.children = node.children.filter((item) => {
                    if (item.type === 'raw' || item.type === 'comment') {
                        let str = item.value?.trim();
                        str = str.replace(/^<!--(.*?)-->/, '$1');
                        if (str === openDelimiter) {
                            start = true;
                            return false;
                        }
                        if (str === closeDelimiter) {
                            start = false;
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    return !start;
                });
            }
        });
    };
};
export default rehypeIgnore;
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

When I try to run storybook, I recently started seeing this error. Nothing has changed with respect to storybook in package.json

I dont directly use rehype-ignore, looks like its a dependency. It seems that webpack 4 doesn't support optional chaining, how can I configure storybook so that builds wont fail?

I tried a couple of leads linking to SO and Github issues, tried a few solutions but had no luck, looking for more guidance on how I can configure my webpack better

Comment: Can you find a webpack.config.js file? There should be rules for the loader for js files. Also, do you have a .babelrc?

Comment: @qrsngky it's a nextjs project,  there is only next.config.js. But optional chaining works fine in nextjs app. I only have issue with the storybook builds

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading storybook to web pack 5 and version 7-beta solved the issue for me